# why rss feed of SO doesn't include answers?

Tags: support, feed

i subscribe to SO rss, but it's not including answer to questions?

Comment: If you subscribe to the rss feed for a question you'll see the answers that are posted to it. A feed of all the answers might be a bit overwhelming.

Comment: @ChrisF, it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last 80 seconds, SO received 20 new questions and answers (total posts).

The main feed would have to be refreshed every 2 minutes to capture all the new posts (both questions and answers), and this is not the peak activity time for SO.

So the main feed only contains newly asked questions, which still has to be refreshed every 10 minutes to capture all the questions (during this non-peak time).

Comment: Does SO at least have the feature to enable an all-answers RSS feed? If someone else purchased the SO engine to run their own private exchange with far less volume, it could be very reasonable for them to want the ability for an all-answer RSS feed. It should be an option within SO that just happens to be turned off for high volume use cases, like the flagship site. Is that true about the SO backend?